# get polynomials out of an interpolating Function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to extract the coefficients or polynomial that results from an interpolation in Mathematica?

These polynomials are functions over the real axis. But I need to evaluate one of these polynomials with a complex number. Something like this:

```
data = Table[ Exp[-x^2], {x,-4,4,0.4} ];
f = ListInterpolation[ data, {{-4,4}} ];

z = 3.1 + I;

g = Polynomial which evaluates f[3.1] or f[Re[z]]
g[z]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: suggest you ask on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Strongly related: "[Extracting the function from InterpolatingFunction object](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59944/280)."

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListInterpolation.html) if you click on Details and Options it says it returns an InterpolatingFunction and according to the documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) and scroll down to the bottom and click on Properties and Relations it says it does Piecewise polynomial interpolation. Thus I don't think you are going to get "the polynomial" from this. But that does show how you could construct your own Piecewise InterpolatingPolynomial from your data. Or you could use Fit documented [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html) to construct a single polynomial.